# Loading speed and use of resources with CSS advanced selectors

Tags: css

I am starting making use of "advanced" selectors, and even though with this I am being able to locate and identify all elements on my HTML without needing to classify them or give them an ID, I am worried about if this way of programming (which I suppose is the correct one as most of the online templates/plugins etc... use it) does not need more resources and increases loading times than just using classes and ID's as selectors.

For example, the code above could be done just with some simple selectors, IDs and classes, but I preferred to do it as you can see:

```
.impairsRight > div{  
   float: right;
   width: 100%;
   margin-bottom:15px;}

.content-hola .impairsRight > div:nth-child(odd) > p {
    margin-left:30%;}

.content-hola  .impairsRight > div:nth-child(even) > p {
    margin-right:30%;}

.impairsRight > div:nth-child(even) > h5 {
    text-align:right;}

.impairsRight > div:nth-child(odd) > h5 {
    text-align:left;}
```

Is this heavier on size/speed/use of resources than simple ones? Is there any tool or website that can test this kind of things? (not only loading times, algo resources needings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never heard of a case where the use of CSS selectors impair the speed of a web site to a noticable degree.
This is really nothing you have to worry about.